# Correct use of "wake up"

Tags: phrasal-verbs, compounds

English isn't my native language (Spanish is), so this question may be very basic, but it is worse not to ask.

Which of these two phrases is the correct one?

> 1. I'm trying to *wake* and get up from my bed
> 2. I'm trying to *wake up* and get up from my bed

Comment: The second one is standard.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Either would suffice, but #2 is more natural.

Actually, most natural would be:

> I'm trying to wake up and get out of bed.

Comment: Aye, the second *up* should not really be there.

Answer (score 3):

"Wake" without "up" is possible in both transitive ("wake somebody") and intransitive ("I woke") senses; but it sounds rather literary: "wake up" is more common in speech in either sense.

There is a third alternative, "awake". It is rare in the transitive sense ("I awoke them") but I think it is more common than "wake" when used intransitively ("When I awoke, ..."). But it is also much less common in speech than "wake up".

Answer (score 1):

It reminds me of the Bob Marley song:

"You['ve] got to get up, stand up: stand up for your rights"

Repeating "up" sounds natural to English speakers.

But Robusto has a better construct. In fact, an example from American popular song:

"When the Red Red Robin comes Bob Bob Bobbin' along"

> Wake up, wake up you sleepy head
>
> Get up, get out of bed
>
> Cheer up, cheer up the sun is red
>
> Live, love, laugh and be happy