# "Get up" vs. "wake up"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, verbs, phrasal-verbs, simple-past

I am not a native English speaker. Whet I get up late in the morning, I get to inform my office that I am late for that particular day. And I am always confused if I should use "I just got up" or "I just woke up". Which one is it?

Comment: Check: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15381/correct-use-of-wake-up

Comment: You may find  [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com) useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To *[wake up](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/wake+up)* is to:-

> stop sleeping; "She woke up to the sound of the alarm clock"

whereas to *[get up](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/get+up)* is to:-

> 1. a. To arise from bed or rise to one's feet.

so, for instance, I *woke up* at about half-past seven this morning, but I didn't *get up* until quarter to nine, because I am feeling in a bone-idle mood this morning.  If you are late for work and want to keep your job, you would be well-advised to say *I just woke up*.

Comment: Unless you are sleep-walking, you can't *get up* until you have *woken up*.